# Calling func textfield(...) without using keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a button that changes the value of a text field. 
How do I get that to also execute the textField function bellow, as if the value was typed inside the text field?

This function only works if you're using the keyboard to type. I need to also call it without using the keyboard.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    print("some actions her")

    return true
}
```

Comment: Basically never call system delegate methods which contain `will / did / should` yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You don't. This delegate method is only called as a user types. It will never be called if you explicitly set the `text` property of the text field. And this is a good thing. It's not uncommon to set the text field's `text` inside the `shouldChangeCharactersIn` delegate method. If setting the text caused the delegate method to be called you could end up with infinite recursion.

Since your code is explicitly setting the text, there is no need for the delegate to be called. Simply set the text to the desired value.

If there is logic to format the text or some other processing, put that logic in another function and then you can call that function from two places - from `shouldChangeCharactersIn` and from wherever you set the text field's text.